# Simple MOLAP solution

Tags: database, logging, text-files, olap

To analyze lots of text logs I did some hackery that looks like this:

1. Locally import logs into Access
2. Reprocess Cube link to previous mdb in Analisis Service 2000 (yes it is 2k)
3. Use Excel to visualize Cube (it is not big - up to milions raw entries)

My hackery is a succes and more people are demanding an access to my Tool. As you see I see more automating and easier deployment.

Do you now some tools/libraries that would give me the same but with easier deployment?
Kind of **embedded OLAP** service?

**Edit:** I heard of Mondrian but we don't do much with Java. Have you seen something similiar done for .Net/Win32 ? Comercial is also OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try the other free open source OLAP server, PALO from Jedox (www.palo.net)

Comment: I am using jedox and palo professionally and I am 100% sure that there is no way to use jedox as a free server!

Comment: @LyubomirVelchev I'm sure it is possible. You can download the code for the open source olap server [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/palo/code/HEAD/tree/). - edit: Just saw this is from 2008. Well, perhaps it will help someone. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely familiar with the implications of Step 2 in your approach above, but if you're looking for a more robust OLAP solution, it might be worth your while to check out [Mondrian, the open-source OLAP / Analysis services](http://mondrian.pentaho.org/) module of Pentaho.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that Mondrian is better than SSAS but I do know that its free and you independently distribute it. It uses XMLA and its cube definition XML file is almost the same as SSAS.

Answer (score 0):

SQl 2K is fine. Stick the cube on a server everyone can see on the network, and tell em to use Excel to connect to it.